# amortized analysis and one basic question (is there any simple example)?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity

I see two sentences:

> total amortized cost of a sequence of operations must be an upper
> bound on the total actual cost of the sequence

> When assigning amortized costs to operations on a data structure, you
> need to ensure that, for any sequence of operations performed, that
> the sum of the amortized costs is always at least as big as the sum of
> the actual costs of those operations.

my challenge is two things:

A) both of them meaning: `amortized cost >= Real Cost of operation?` I think amortized is (n* real cost).

B) is there any example to more clear me to understand? a real and short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that amortization solves is that common operations may trigger occasional slow ones.  Therefore if we add up the worst cases, we are effectively looking at how the program would perform if garbage collection is always running and every data structure had to be moved in memory every time.  But if we ignore the worst cases, we are effectively ignoring that garbage collection sometimes does run, and large lists sometimes do run out of allocated space and have to be moved to a bigger bucket.

We solve this by gradually writing off occasional big operations over time.  We write it off as soon as we realize that it may be needed some day.  Which means that the amortized cost is usually bigger than the real cost, because it includes that future work, but occasionally the real cost is way bigger than the amortized.  And, on average, they come out to around the same.

The standard example people start with is a list implementation where we allocate 2x the space we currently need, and then reallocate and move it if we use up space.  When I run `foo.append(...)` in this implementation, usually I just insert.  But occasionally I have to copy the whole large list.  However if I just copied and the list had `n` items, after I `append` `n` times I will need to copy `2n` items to a bigger space.  Therefore my amortized analysis of what it costs to `append` includes the cost of an insert and moving 2 items.  And over the next `n` times I call `append` it my estimate exceeds the real cost `n-1` times and is less the `n`th time, but averages out exactly right.

(Python's real list implementation works like this except that the new list is around 9/8 the size of the old one.)